# Determine number of possible combinations of String in Java

Tags: java, android

I was able to figure out how to produce a random alphanumeric string after refreshing my Java Knowledge. Here is a my method:

```
private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

 String idGenerator(int count){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while (count-- != 0) {

            int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());

            builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));

        }

        return builder.toString();
}
```

However, I was wondering how many possible combinations of string can my `idGenerator` method produce? Is there a built in method, class or a possible algorithm to determine this? Thanks!

Comment: Its simple mathematics... Your code can generate `36!`(factorial 36) combinations

Comment: There're *36* possibilities for a single character (26 letters + 10 digits), and `36**count` for the string of `count` length

Comment: permutation and combination

Comment: yup. just looked at my discrete mathematics notes 2 years ago. checking for permutations and combinations.

Comment: permutations and combinations only apply if you are not allowing repetition of characters.

Comment: numberOfPermutations = numberOfStates ^ numberOfBits;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a *great number of* combinations, so, IMHO, `BigInteger` is 
a right choice

```
public static BigInteger getPossibleCombinationsCount(int count) {
  return BigInteger.valueOf(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length()).pow(count);
}
```

Comment: `long` required for `count > 5`. `BigInteger` required for `count > 12`

Comment: with this line `BigInteger count = getPossibleCombinationsCount(12);
Log.i("Combinations Count",String.valueOf(count));` the answer is 4738381338321616896. I am not sure if this is correct lol.

Comment: rereading my statistics notes. seems like this is the way to go so far since BigInteger covers a a large range of numbers

Comment: @Miguel Rivera: The answer `4738381338321616896` for `12` is right, it's exactly `36**12`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you for the insight about getting the number of combinations.

Answer (score 3):

One helper method:

```
public static int getPossibleCombinationsCount(int count) {
    return Math.pow(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length() , count);
}
```

Comment: there should be `ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length ** count` (`length` in `count`'s *power*), not just a multiplicaton, you can use `Math` for power